# Php - get every value from counted array

Tags: php, arrays, count, key

I have this current array:

```
Array ( [name1] => 3 [name2] => 2 [name3] => 1 [name4] => 2 [name5] => 1 )
```

ps: I get this array when i use array_count_values() on some other array.

My question, how to get every value from this array in an other array, the expected result:

```
Array (name1, name2, name3, name4, name5)
```

I tried:

```
while ($name = current($array)) {
    echo key($array).'<br />';
    next($array);
}
```

but didnt work for me. anybody could help?? Greetings!!

Comment: **FYI** `name1, name2, name3, name4, name5` were keys in the first array and not the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on your original array, especially if you don't actually need to count the values.
You may also need [array_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) combined with that if you need an indexed array.

Comment: Did you read the question fully.This answer is no way related to the one OP had asked

Comment: @krishna OP mentioned he gets this array when he uses array_count_values() on some other array. So he has an array in the first place with name1 3 times, name2 2 times, etc. It seems logical to me to try this.

Comment: do you know what `array_count_values()` does. if you use `array_unique()` the purpose of using `array_count_values()` fails

Comment: I get that, i mean using array_unique() on the original array, because for getting the array `Array (name1, name2, name3, name4, name5)` he doesn't need to count the values.